# obtener milisegundos en una fecha que elija

Tags: php

estoy tratando de obtener los milisegundos y almacenarlos en una variable para que pueda guardarlos en mysql ya que el cliente me pidio que sacara la diferencia entre la hora de llegada y la de final para esto es necesario los milisegundos y cnentesimas

aqui el codigo

```
<?php
$horaini="11:36:38:79";
$horafin="14:20:38:49";
$f1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s:u", $horaini);
$f2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s:u", $horafin);

 $d = $f1->diff($f2);

 echo  $d->format('%H:%i:%s%.u');
 

 ?>
```

eh intentado de varias formas y no me saca la diferencia puesto que neesito almacenarla en una tabla de mysql

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado que esperas en ese código?

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que la mayoría de las funciones te dan fechas en formato Unix que solo es hasta segundos, una opción es obtener la diferencia de los milisegundos aparte:

```
$hi=explode(":","11:36:38:79");
$hf=explode(":","14:20:38:49");
$f1 = date_timestamp_get(DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s", $hi[0].":".$hi[1].":".$hi[2]));
$f2 = date_timestamp_get(DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s", $hf[0].":".$hf[1].":".$hf[2]));
$micro=$hf[3]-$hi[3];
$diff=($f2-$f1)*1000+$micro;
$h=floor($diff/3600000);
$m=floor(($diff/3600000-$h)*60);
$s=floor((($diff/3600000-$h)*60-$m)*60);
$u=floor(((($diff/3600000-$h)*60-$m)*60-$s)*1000);
echo $h.":".$m.":".$s.":".$u;
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me Funciona con el dato fijo pero no con un valor de una base de datos almacenado en una variable.

el campo es DateTime(3)

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/346065)